# "It’s one of the greatest American literature." Is this sentence correct?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability

It's a quote from a material of an online English school.
https://eikaiwa.weblio.jp/information/speaking-material/conversation-material/expert-literature-and-art

"It’s one of the greatest American literature."

The word, litarature, is uncountable, isn't it?  This sentence sounds very awkward to me.  I believe it should be "one of the greatest American litarature classics" or something like that.

Is this material grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4):

That sentence is not grammatical English.

You could say about *The Great Gatsby* that

> It’s one of the greatest
> *novels in* American literature.

There is no way to tell without context whether the writer has erred or some words were inadvertently dropped.

Your suggestion of

> It's one of the greatest American literature classics.

is awkward even if grammatically acceptable.

> It's one of the classics of American literature.

would be better.

You would probably never say "one of the greatest classics" since "classics" are already implicitly "great".